# Does redis persistence blocks read and write request

Tags: caching, redis

I am using redis and saving data to disk in certain time interval. I  see normally redis read and write time is order of .2 miliseconds but I see few peeks of order of 30 milliseconds. I read redis forks a background process to write data into disk , is forking happens on same (redis use single thread to serve all requests) thread which serves read and write request. 
If this is true I want a solution such that persistence would not increase latency for read and write request.

Answer (score 0):

If you issue a [`BGSAVE`](http://redis.io/commands/bgsave), the background save will fork. The OS needs to have a lazy separate CPU thread available ofcourse, for this not to impact Redis-server's main thread. If you configure `save` in redis.conf, a `BGSAVE` is basically what happens. I would configure it to **off** and issue BGSAVE manually while troubleshooting.

If you issue a [`SAVE`](http://redis.io/commands/save), saving will be syncronous, and other clients will have to wait.

See also [here](http://redis.io/topics/persistence). You might want to skip rdb snapshotting altogether, and rely on AOF.

Also see my remark on sensitive data: [SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208798/redis-replication-config/22329319#comment34022621_22329319). There are many ways to make sure your data is safe. Disk-persistence is only one of them.

Hope this helps, TW